# Normalizing windows in tensorflow dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build a windowed dataset from a univariate time series. 
The idea is if the series looks like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and the window length was 2, then
I'd take windows of length 3 to account for 2 X features and Y target output, so
`[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]`  then I'll shuffle them up to avoid bias from that, and split out the input features from target output for each window: `[[[1, 2], [3]], [[2, 3], [4]], [[3, 4], [5]], [[4, 5], [6]]]`

```
def windowed_dataset(series):
    # Initially the data is (N,) expand dims to (N, 1)
    series = tf.expand_dims(series, axis=-1)

    # Tensorflow Dataset from the array
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)

    # Create the windows that will serve as input features and label (hence +1)
    ds = ds.window(window_len + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    ds = ds.flat_map(lambda w: w.batch(window_len + 1))

    # randomize order 
    ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_buffer)
    # Separate  the inputs and the target output(label)
    ds = ds.map(lambda w: (w[:-1], w[-1]))
    return ds.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```

However I'd like to add some normalization. For example if my window is `w=[1, 2, 3]` then I'd like to normalize according to `[p/w[0] - 1 for p in w]`

I thought I could achieve this with `ds.map` and

```
    def normalize_window(w):
      return [((i/w[0]) -1) for i in w]


    ds = ds.map(normalize_window)
```

because map is supposed to apply the function to each window in the dataset, but this didn't work. All the example in tensorflow dataset docs use `map` with lambda functions but I presume it works with regular functions too

Does anyone know how it should be done?

EDIT

The traceback I get is

```
<ipython-input-39-929295e1b775> in <module>()
----> 1 dataset = model_forecast_datasets(btc_model, np_data[:6])

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    263       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    264         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 265           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    266         else:
    267           raise

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-38-b3d0f7e17689>:12 normalize_window  *
        return [(i/w[0] -1) for i in w]
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:561 __iter__
        self._disallow_iteration()
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:557 _disallow_iteration
        self._disallow_in_graph_mode("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:537 _disallow_in_graph_mode
        " this function with @tf.function.".format(task))

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
```

Comment: Do you get an error or do you get unexpected results? Please share more details on what happened.

Comment: @thushv89 added the traceback of the attempt with list comprehension

Comment: Well yeah, the problem is obvious, it's the `for i in w` part. You are trying to iterate a tensor in that function. Instead try, `return w/w[0] - 1`

Comment: @thushv89 I'm kinda confused why `w` is a tensor and not a `WindowedDataset` however, hmm

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice the `ds.window` part. See if the above works, if not, I'll have a deeper look

Comment: @thushv89 it does work on the tensor, yeah

Answer (score 1):

You would need a function that vectorizes the calculation, something like

```
def normalize(data):
    mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(data)
    std = tf.math.reduce_std(data)
    data = tf.subtract(data, mean)
    data = tf.divide(data, std)
    return data

ds = ds.map(normalize)
```

Edit: For your specific normalization this may work:

```
def normalize(data):
    data1 = tf.subtract(data, tf.constant(1))
    data1 = tf.divide(data1, data[0])
    return data1
```

(this would have to go after batching `ds = ds.flat_map(...)`